# AForge FFT gives a different result than Accelerate FFT

Tags: ios, fft, aforge

Not sure what I am doing wrong. The results I get from the Accelerate framework seem incorrect to me.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Here are some graphs comparing AForge with vDPS
[image: Here are some graphs comparing AForge with vDPS]
This is the vDSP Code I run

```
fftSetup = vDSP_create_fftsetup( 16, 2);

 // Convert the data into a DSPSplitComplex 
int samples = spectrumDataSize;
int samplesOver2 = samples/2;

DSPSplitComplex * complexData = new DSPSplitComplex;
float *realpart = (float *)calloc(samplesOver2, sizeof(float));
float *imagpart = (float *)calloc(samplesOver2, sizeof(float));
complexData->realp = realpart;
complexData->imagp = imagpart;    

vDSP_ctoz((DSPComplex *)realData, 2, complexData, 1,samplesOver2);

// Calculate the FFT
// ( I'm assuming here you've already called vDSP_create_fftsetup() )
vDSP_fft_zrip(fftSetup, complexData, 1, log2f(samples), FFT_FORWARD);

// Scale the data
//float scale = (float) FFT_SCALE; //scale is 32
vDSP_vsmul(complexData->realp, 1, &scale, complexData->realp, 1,samplesOver2);
vDSP_vsmul(complexData->imagp, 1, &scale, complexData->imagp, 1, samplesOver2);


vDSP_zvabs(complexData, 1, spectrumData, 1, samples);

free(complexData->realp);
free(complexData->imagp);
delete complexData;

// All done!
return spectrumData;
```

This is what I do in AForge

```
        foreach (float f in floatData)
            {
                if (i >= this.fft.Length)
                    break;
                this.fft[i++] = new Complex(f * fftSize, 0);
            }
            AForge.Math.FourierTransform.FFT(this.fft, FourierTransform.Direction.Forward);
```

Comment: Couple of questions.. are the vDSP_create_fftsetup args and scale correct (what is spectrumDataSize?) ? How many results are you expecting (i.e. what is spectrumData, how are you drawing it?)?

Comment: How do I know if the scale and fftsetup args are correct? The spectrumDataSize is the size of the signal. It's up to 2^14 samples long.  The displayed data is the magnitude of the output from the fft.

Comment: the scale and fftsetup args depend on the number of input samples. If you aren't calculating them then they probably aren't correct. I'll add an answer, but i don't think that is your main problem. I think it's more how you interpret the results.. but i'd have to see more code

Comment: i think this like is wrong. vDSP_zvabs(complexData, 1, spectrumData, 1, samples); I think it should be 2,1

Comment: what additional code do you need to see? The graph is just of the output vector of both of the above.

Comment: What are you showing in the plots? There are two graphs for AForge and two for iOS. Is the first one input? If so, why is it different for aForge and iOS? How many samples did you plot from spectrumData? As answered below, you calculated samples, but that overruns the buffer, and the correct number to calculate is samplesOver2 or samplesOver2+1.

Comment: The bottom-left graph appears to be symmetric about a vertical center line. This is expected if you transform an N-element real signal and plot the magnitudes of N complex outputs. The outputs after the center are redundant. vDSP_fft_zrop does not return that redundant data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the following subroutine

```
vDSP_ctoz((DSPComplex *)realData, 2, complexData, 1,samplesOver2);
```

is executed, `complexData` has `samplesOver2` elements.  But soon after that, you call

```
vDSP_zvabs(complexData, 1, spectrumData, 1, samples);
```

which expects `complexData` to have `samples` elements, i.e. twice as many.  This cannot be.

Also, how is `realData` laid out?  I ask because `vDSP_ctoz` expects its first argument to be laid out in the form

```
real0, imag0, real1, imag1, ... real(n-1), imag(n-1).
```

If your data is indeed real, then `imag0, imag1, ... imag(n-1)` should all be 0.  If it is not, then `vDSP_ctoz` may not be expecting that.  (Unless you are packing the real data in some clever way, which would be two [sic] clever by half!)

Finally, `vDSP_create_fftsetup( 16, 2);` should probably be changed to

```
vDSP_create_fftsetup(16, 0);
```

===================================================================

My sample code appended in postscript:

```
  FFTSetup fftSetup = vDSP_create_fftsetup(
                                           16,         // vDSP_Length __vDSP_log2n,
                                           kFFTRadix2  // FFTRadix __vDSP_radix
                                           // CAUTION: kFFTRadix2 is an enum that is equal to 0
                                           //          kFFTRadix5 is an enum that is equal to 2
                                           // DO NOT USE 2 IF YOU MEAN kFFTRadix2
                                           );
  NSAssert(fftSetup != NULL, @"vDSP_create_fftsetup() failed to allocate storage");

  int numSamples = 65536;  // numSamples must be an integer power of 2; in this case 65536 = 2 ^ 16
  float realData[numSamples];

  // Prepare the real data with (ahem) fake data, in this case
  // the sum of 3 sinusoidal waves representing a C major chord.
  // The fake data is rigged to have a sampling frequency of 44100 Hz (as for a CD).
  // As always, the Nyquist frequency is just half the sampling frequency, i.e., 22050 Hz.
  for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; i++)
  {
    realData[i] = sin(2 * M_PI * 261.76300048828125 * i / 44100.0)  // C4 = 261.626 Hz
                + sin(2 * M_PI * 329.72717285156250 * i / 44100.0)  // E4 = 329.628 Hz
                + sin(2 * M_PI * 392.30804443359375 * i / 44100.0); // G4 = 391.995 Hz
  }

  float splitReal[numSamples / 2];
  float splitImag[numSamples / 2];

  DSPSplitComplex splitComplex;
  splitComplex.realp = splitReal;
  splitComplex.imagp = splitImag;

  vDSP_ctoz(
            (const DSPComplex *)realData,  // const DSPComplex __vDSP_C[],
            2,                             // vDSP_Stride __vDSP_strideC,  MUST BE A MULTIPLE OF 2
            &splitComplex,                 // DSPSplitComplex *__vDSP_Z,
            1,                             // vDSP_Stride __vDSP_strideZ,
            (numSamples / 2)               // vDSP_Length __vDSP_size
            );

  vDSP_fft_zrip(
                fftSetup,                               // FFTSetup __vDSP_setup,
                &splitComplex,                          // DSPSplitComplex *__vDSP_ioData,
                1,                                      // vDSP_Stride __vDSP_stride,
                (vDSP_Length)lround(log2(numSamples)),  // vDSP_Length __vDSP_log2n,
                // IMPORTANT: THE PRECEDING ARGUMENT MUST BE LOG_BASE_2 OF THE NUMBER OF floats IN splitComplex
                // FOR OUR EXAMPLE, THIS WOULD BE (numSamples / 2) + (numSamples / 2) = numSamples
                kFFTDirection_Forward                   // FFTDirection __vDSP_direction
                );

  printf("DC component = %f\n", splitComplex.realp[0]);
  printf("Nyquist component = %f\n\n", splitComplex.imagp[0]);

  // Next, we compute the Power Spectral Density (PSD) from the FFT.
  // (The PSD is just the magnitude-squared of the FFT.)
  // (We don't bother with scaling as we are only interested in relative values of the PSD.)
  float powerSpectralDensity[(numSamples / 2) + 1];  // the "+ 1" is to make room for the Nyquist component

  // We move the Nyquist component out of splitComplex.imagp[0] and place it
  // at the end of the array powerSpectralDensity, squaring it as we go:
  powerSpectralDensity[numSamples / 2] = splitComplex.imagp[0] * splitComplex.imagp[0];

  // We can now zero out splitComplex.imagp[0] since the imaginary part of the DC component is, in fact, zero:
  splitComplex.imagp[0] = 0.0;

  // Finally, we compute the squares of the magnitudes of the elements of the FFT:
  vDSP_zvmags(
              &splitComplex,         // DSPSplitComplex *__vDSP_A,
              1,                     // vDSP_Stride __vDSP_I,
              powerSpectralDensity,  // float *__vDSP_C,
              1,                     // vDSP_Stride __vDSP_K,
              (numSamples / 2)       // vDSP_Length __vDSP_N
              );

  // We print out a table of the PSD as a function of frequency
  // Replace the "< 600" in the for-loop below with "<= (numSamples / 2)" if you want
  // the entire spectrum up to and including the Nyquist frequency:
  printf("Frequency_in_Hz    Power_Spectral_Density\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < 600; i++)  
  {
    printf("%f,          %f\n", (i / (float)(numSamples / 2)) * 22050.0, powerSpectralDensity[i]);
    // Recall that the array index i = 0 corresponds to zero frequency
    // and that i = (numSamples / 2) corresponds to the Nyquist frequency of 22050 Hz.
    // Frequency values intermediate between these two limits are scaled proportionally (linearly).
  }

  // The output PSD should be zero everywhere except at the three frequencies
  // corresponding to the C major triad.  It should be something like this:

/***************************************************************************
 DC component = -0.000000
 Nyquist component = -0.000000

 Frequency_in_Hz    Power_Spectral_Density
 0.000000,          0.000000
 0.672913,          0.000000
 1.345825,          0.000000
 2.018738,          0.000000
 2.691650,          0.000000
 .
 .
 .
 260.417175,          0.000000
 261.090088,          0.000000
 261.763000,          4294967296.000000
 262.435913,          0.000000
 263.108826,          0.000000
 .
 .
 .
 328.381348,          0.000000
 329.054260,          0.000000
 329.727173,          4294967296.000000
 330.400085,          0.000000
 331.072998,          0.000000
 .
 .
 .
 390.962219,          0.000000
 391.635132,          0.000000
 392.308044,          4294966784.000000
 392.980957,          0.000000
 393.653870,          0.000000
 .
 .
 .
***************************************************************************/

  vDSP_destroy_fftsetup(fftSetup);
```

Comment: the real data is real0,real1,real2. At this point the imaginary part is all 0. (the real data comes from audio)  Should the real data ba real0,0,real1?

Comment: vDSP_ctoz is not being used here to convert interleaved complex data to separated complex data; it is being used to change the layout of the real data in realData to the format required by vDSP_fft_zrip. (This layout is an unfortunate legacy artifact.) So the data in realData should be just real0, real1, real2,... After the call, complexData->realp contains real0, real2, real4,..., and complexData->imago contains real1, real3, real5,...

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
vDSP_zvabs(complexData, 1, spectrumData, 1, samples);
```

should be:

```
float cr = complexData->realp[0], ci = complexData->imagp[0];
vDSP_zvabs(complexData, 1, spectrumData, 1, samplesOver2);
spectrumData[0] = cr*cr;
spectrumData[samplesOver2] = ci*ci; // See remarks below.
```

This because the real-to-complex FFT of N samples returns N/2+1 results. Two of the results are real numbers, which are packed into complexData->realp[0] and complexData->imagp[0]. The remaining N/2-1 results are complex numbers, stored normally with the real components in complexData->realp[i] and the imaginary components in complexData->imagp[i], for 0 < i < N/2.

vDSP_zvabs computes the magnitudes of the complex numbers, except that the first output (in spectrumData[0]) is incorrect due to the packing of two numbers into the [0] elements. Overwriting spectrumData[0] with cr*cr corrects that. You can also write the magnitude of the other packed element (the Nyquist frequency) into spectrumData[samplesOver2], if space has been provided for that.

Some other notes:

spectrumDataSize must be a power of two.

It is not ideal practice to calculate the base-two logarithm as log2f(samples). I think we (Apple) have made log2f return exactly correct results for integer powers of two, but depending on floating-point exactness should be avoided unless care has been taken to be very certain of it.

There is no need to dynamically allocate a DSPSplitComplex with “new”. It is POD (plain old data) containing just two pointers, so you can simply declare “DSPSplitComplex complexData” and use it as a struct, rather than a pointer to a struct.

Comment: thanks for the comment. But I don't see difference in the spectrum data just at postions 0 and samplesOver2. The signal is significantly different and this does not seem to explain those differences.

Comment: Please see my comments above, on your question. It appears that aForge returns a “complete” spectrum, including redundant data (the right is a mirror image of the left), but vDSP returns only the left half (and center point). Your vDSP_zvabs call overran memory, so data was corrupted.

Comment: I understand that. I (may have) have found my problem. I was assuming that the real data was real0,real1,real2 not real0,img0,real1,img0. Making that change fixed my problem. I didn't do the above fix but will look into it to see if it provides further improvement.

Comment: The real output from vDSP_fft_zrip is real0, real1, real2, real3,... real[N/2-1]. The imaginary output is real[N/2], imag1, imag2, imag3,... imag[N/2-1].

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts..

```
int numberOfInputSamples = ..;
int numberOfInputSamplesOver2 = numberOfInputSamples/2;

fftSetup = vDSP_create_fftsetup( log2(numberOfInputSamples), FFT_RADIX2 );
...
Float32 scale = (Float32) 1.0 / (2 * numberOfInputSamples);                
...
float *spectrumData = (float *)calloc( numberOfInputSamplesOver2, sizeof(float));
vDSP_zvabs( complexData, 1, spectrumData, 1, numberOfInputSamplesOver2 );
```

so at the end you will have numberOfInputSamplesOver2 float magnitudes, right?

*(technically it is numberOfInputSamplesOver2+1 but the whole packing thing is another question)*

Comment: the problem with this is that the results don't seem similar to those that I get from AForge. Would you expect that?

Comment: different how? different scale? not related in any way? If they are completely different can't you determine which is correct?

Comment: they are completely different as shown in the graphs. I believe AForge is correct as when I use it's output I get better results.

Comment: so making the changes in my answer didn't change the graph?

Comment: the scale changed. but the form of the graph was the same.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be computing one FFT for length N/2, and one for length N.  Thus the different results for different length FFTs.

Comment: Why do you think that's true? I was under the impression that the samplesOver2 was related to packing the data.  How can I make iOS computer the FFT for length N?

Answer (score 0):

I assume since you are calling `vDSP_ctoz` that your data is not in even-odd. If that IS the case, you also need to unpack it after the fft.

From [vDSP Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vDSP_Programming_Guide/UsingFourierTransforms/UsingFourierTransforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005147-CH202-BBCEAFDD):

> Applications that call the real FFT may have to use two transformation functions, one before the FFT call and one after. This is required if the input array is not in the even-odd split configuration.

[Sample code illustrating this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vDSP_Programming_Guide/SampleCode/SampleCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005147-CH205-45465)

Hope that helps.

Comment: That sample code includes both a forward and a reverse transform, so the data is back in the time domain. In this question, the data in the frequency domain is being used. It is complex data, not even-odd real data, so there is no need to rearrange it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not at all familiar with either AForge or Accelerate, but I did encounter some problems when upgrading FFT libraries in another project dealing with 2D images, which look to me as similar to yours.

It turns out that output data representation from FFT libraries isn't unique, and for some applications the output data is much more convenient if "swapped", so as to put low frequencies in the center rather than in corners.

If you check this page on a FFT algorithm, http://www.eso.org/sci/software/eclipse/eug/eug/man/fft.html , you'll notice that both formats are supported, and the swap structure is described (at bottom).

It seems to me that the data you graphed at the right would look much more like the ones on the left, were you to swap (mirror) the right half of the data array around the center.